# Extracting a value from a same file from multiple directories

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Directory name F1 F2 F3……F120

Inside each directory, a file with a common name ‘xyz.txt’

File xyz.txt has a value

Example:

```
F1
Xyz.txt
3.345e-2

F2
Xyz.txt
2.345e-2

F3
Xyz.txt
1.345e-2
--

F120
Xyz.txt
0.345e-2
```

I want to extract these values and paste them in a single file say ‘new.txt’ in a column like

```
New.txt
 3.345e-2
2.345e-2
1.345e-2
---
0.345e-2
```

Any help please? Thank you so much.

Comment: `for i in /path/to/F[[:digit:]]*/Xyz.txt; do echo $(<$i); done`?

Comment: `cat F{1..120}/Xyz.txt > New.txt`?

Comment: @j1-lee thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you :)

Comment: @saya : So, the Xyz.txt file consist only of a single line, holding this value? Is the order of these values in the output important?

Comment: Also read over the pages at http://idownvotedbecau.se/ for great writeups on why asking a good question andf asking it well are important. :)

Answer (score 1):

If your files look very similar then you can use `grep`. For example:

```
cat F{1..120}/xyz.txt | grep -E '^[0-9][.][0-9]{3}e-[0-9]$' > new.txt
```

This is a general example as any number can be anything. The regular expression says that the whole line must consist of: a any digit [0-9], a dot character [.], three digits [0-9]{3}, the letter 'e' and any digit [0-9].

If your data is more regular you can also try more simple solution:

```
cat F{1..120}/xyz.txt | grep -E '^[0-9][.]345e-2$' > new.txt
```

In this solution only the first digit can be anything.

Comment: The regex hardcodes a minus after the `e`, which is suggested by the examples in the question, but might not actually be a correct generalization.

Comment: Is there a need to use `cat` and a pipe?

Comment: @tripleee, if the data are regular like in the example, my solution will works. OP marked as if each file was the same.

Comment: @potong, if you want to have every matching value in new line you should use `cat` and pipe. First, this solution is much clear and easy to understand. Secondly, if I execute the command `grep -E '^[0-9][.]345e-2$' F{1..120}/xyz.txt` my output will looks like: `F1/xyz.txt:3.345e-2`. There will also be information about the name of the file the selected line comes from. The OP only wants the results, so this solution will not be correct.

Comment: Perhaps forgo the cat and pipe and just use the `-h` option in grep to hide the file name of the match?

Comment: This is another option. It will be work. But the solution with `cat` and pipe is more readable for most people :)

Answer (score 1):

If your files might contain something else than the line, but the line you want to extract can be unambiguously extracted with a regex, you can use

```sh
sed -n '/^[0-9]\.[0-9]*e-*[0-9]*$/p' F*/Xyz.txt >new.txt
```

The same can be done with `grep`, but you have to separately tell it to not print the file name.  The `-x` option can be used as a convenience to simplify the regex.

```sh
grep -h -x '[0-9]\.[0-9]*e-*[0-9]*' F*/Xyz.txt >new.txt
```

If you have some files which match the wildcard which should be excluded, try a more complex wildcard, or multiple wildcards which only match exactly the files you want, like maybe `F[1-9]/Xyz.txt F[1-9][0-9]/Xyz.txt F1[0-9][0-9]/Xyz.txt`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU parallel and grep):

```
parallel -k grep -hE '^[0-9][.][0-9]{3}e-[0-9]$' F{}/xyz.txt ::: {1..120}
```

Process files in parallel but output results in order.

Comment: Thank you all! I really appreciate!! 

Answer (score 0):

If the files contain just one line, and you want the whole thing, you can use `bash` range expansion:

```
cat /path/to/F{1..120}/Xyz.txt > output.txt
```

(this keeps the order too).

If the files have more lines, and you need to actually extract the value, use `grep -o` (`-o` is not posix, but your `grep` probably has it).

```
grep -o '[0-9].345-e2' /path/to/F{1..120}/Xyz.txt > output.txt
```